# What is correct Sampling frequency value?

Tags: filtering, microcontroller, frequency, pic, sampling

what is correct Sampling frequency (sampling rate) in the given [code](http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=ZMaddtj8)? Is it 8kHz? I'm having trouble to find it.

Comment: Looks like 8KHz according with comments: 8KS/s Sample Rate

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This comment suggests 8kHz

```
.equ        TIMECONST, #32000   ;Use 32000 samples (4 seconds) as constant to find peak
```

and this section of the code specifically says "8KS/s"

```
;Setup Timer 1 for sampling delay: Tcy = 16MHz (64MHz Clock) 
    mov     #0x8000,w1      ;8KS/s at Tcy=16MHz
    mov     w1,T1CON        ;1:1, Int Clk, ON
    mov     #2000,W1        ;Load PR1 for delay, 8KS/s Sample Rate @16MHz Internal
    mov     w1,PR1
```

Comment: The KS/s is equal to kHz?

Comment: KS/s means "kilosamples per second", so Yes, but `Hz` is more properly used in the measurement - or generation - of waveforms..